# Should I save user cookie consent in a custom post type or make a custom database table?

Tags: custom-post-types, database, privacy

What is the better solution for storing large number of user consents: saving them as entries of a custom post type or create custom database tables?

The consents will be remembered for half a year. Possibly between 1000 and 5000 consents a day.

The consents will not require custom post meta. Each entry will contain:

- name in this format: IP + '_' + timestamp
- content: multidimensional array with the consent information, privacy policy update date and a list of tracking tools that were enabled at the time of consent.

Comment: usually cookies are enough, how are you going to tie the consent to the user so that it identifies and remembers that they have/haven't consented? There's a high chance that the scheme you proposed would eliminate page caching as a possibility, and if what the user is consenting for is just the loading of 3rd party trackers then storing that consent server side isn't necessary unless the server itself is doing the tracking. You would want to store consent if you were collecting storing and processing the data yourself on the server.